# How can I include Javascript script tags in my Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I'm using MooTools 1.4.  How do I dynamically include script tags on my page?  The response from the Ajax requset below is supposed to contain  tags ...

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('submit').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        var filename = $('filename').value;
        //prevent the page from changing
        event.stop();
        //make the ajax call
        var req = new Request({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'renderpage?id=' + escape(filename),
            data: { },
            evalScripts: true,
            onRequest: function() { 
                // on request
            },
            onComplete: function(response) {
                $('content').set('html',response);
                // Add the Ajax call where we save the data.
                ...
                });
            }
        }).send();
    }); 
});
```

But when I look at the response, they are getting stripped out.  I would like them included and evaluated.  How can I do this?

Comment: How are you looking at the response?  Browsers don't strip out `<script>` tags in such cases, but libraries/frameworks sometimes do. Are you looking at the actual response with something like Firebug?

Comment: what you have is correct but it does not quite work this way. evalScripts does not lazyload script tags with a src, it parses and runs js blocks instead (inline js).

Comment: place inside eval('js code');

Answer (score 2):

Use [Request.HTML](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML).

```
    var req = new Request.HTML({
        url: 'renderpage?id=' + escape(filename),
        update: $('content'),
        onRequest: function() { 
            // on request
        }
    }).get();
```

Comment: +1 A few years later... and you provided me with a very clean solution! Thank you, this should be upvoted more and be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could return the entire response as JS, and eval the response;

Then you can set the html to some variable in the response, like

```
var new_html='(html)';
```

Then you can do this

```
$('content').set('html',new_html);
```

Comment: The content is being returned from an Ajax request with content type text/html.  Are you saying put that whole thing in a string (e.g. var html = "...";) and change the content type to text/javascript?

Comment: If you posted some sample response code, I can show you what I'm talking about...but basically you return text/javascript that does everything you want to do (not just return the html block).

Answer (score -1):

The parameters passed to `onComplete` are:

`nodeTree, xhr, responseHTML, responseScripts`

So:

```
new Request.HTML({
  // ...
  onComplete : function(nodeTree, xhr, responseHTML, responseScripts) {
    eval(responseScripts);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why `eval` them? Read the [HTML.Request doc](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML): _“evalScripts - (boolean: defaults to true) If set to true, script tags inside the response will be evaluated. This overrides the false default from Request.”_